# CSS best way fluid column layout

Tags: css, less

I am creating a webpage that's designed around a 960px 12 column grid layout, where each column is up to 60px wide and has up to 10px of margin on each side. "Up to" because if the page shrinks, the columns should shrink. Now i have trouble making it pixel perfect.

My "CSS" (actually LESS that generates CSS) looks like this

```
.column{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 100%*(10/960);
    &.c1{
        max-width: 60px;
        width: 100%*(60/960);
    }
    &.c2{
        max-width: 140px;
        width: 100%*(140/960);
    }
    &.c3{
        max-width: 220px;
        width: 100%*(220/960);
    }
    &.c4{
        max-width: 300px;
        width: 100%*(300/960);
    }
    &.c5{
        max-width: 380px;
        width: 100%*(380/960);
    }
    &.c6{
        max-width: 460px;
        width: 100%*(460/960);
    }
    &.c7{
        max-width: 540px;
        width: 100%*(540/960);
    }
    &.c8{
        max-width: 620px;
        width: 100%*(620/960);
    }
    &.c9{
        max-width: 700px;
        width: 100%*(700/960);
    }
    &.c10{
        max-width: 780px;
        width: 100%*(780/960);
    }

    &.c11{
        max-width: 860px;
        width: 100%*(860/960);
    }
    &.c12{
        max-width: 940px;
        width: 100%*(940/960);
    }
}
```

Now, i've created a page with one element that is 12 columns wide on one row.
On row 2 there are 1 element which is 9 columns wide and one 3 column wide.
On row 3, 4 elements each 3 columns wide.

Below is a screenshot. As you can see, they are not pixel perfect aligned. I can't understand why...
[image: Not pixel perfect]

Comment: Do you first and last columns have left and right margins set appropriately in all the rows ?

Comment: I just had a look and actually, the margins are 9px instead of 10px. Why is that? The margin is set to "margin: 1.0416666666666665%", and the width of the parent div is 960px

Comment: I thought so. Can't we set it to a whole-number percentage ?

Comment: Why are you not using Fluid Grid System instead of trying to accommodate a fixed grid to a fluid grid system?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is caused by the way the browser does the rounding. Sometimes you get a extra pixel or so. Sometimes you miss a pixel or so.